# How to display, hear, and control an Android device using PC?

Tags: remote-control

I used Mobizen. However, only the screen shows up. The sound doesn't come from my PC. Also I do not think I can control my Android device from my PC.

Any way to do that?

I want to connect via Wi-fi. Mobizen seems to be web based which means information would go through Internet first before showing up on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control your android device from you PC you just have to install "AirDroid" app from play store you can control all you media of your device from PC and read/write/send/ SMS messages live screen control use device camera from PC and so many features.
You just have to connect your device with a WiFi also with the same WiFi your PC !

Comment: airdroid cannot display my android device full screen.

Comment: So not sexy enough

Comment: Just go to screenshot icon in the AirDroid desktop in your PC browser it can display your device screen with live screen